# How to map over a Spark Vector?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, vector

I have a `mllib.linalg.Vector` in Scala containing `Double` values in range of `(-1; 1)`. I would like to multiply all of the values by, let's say, 100.

For example I'd like to convert `[0.5, 0.3, -0.1]` to `[50, 30, -10]`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.*

val vec = org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors.dense(0.5, 0.3, -0.1)  
val vec2 = Vectors.dense(vec.toArray.map(_*100))
```

Comment: Tbh I was counting on something more sparkish, but this one seems to do the job and isn't that much ugly. I am still wondering why isn't it a feature of mllib